# Signature from OpenSSL (via C#) completely unable to verify in crypto module nodejs

Tags: javascript, c#

I have tried so many different combinations it's insane, I've been debugging this for a while now. Any help is amazing.

The key itself is an Elliptic Curve P521 SHA256 key. This has happened across multiple libraries (BouncyCastle, the native C# Elliptic Curve signer and OpenSSL).

It's meant to return true, but I just get a false with no error explaining why. I have checked that both the public key and data are as they should be, I can even get the public key object from the importEllipticCurvePublicKey.

I just get a return of false, not even an error, it's *extremely* annoying.

Here's my C# signing code:

```
 public static string SignData(string data, string privateKey)
 {
     string dataString = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
     Random rnd = new Random();
     string publickey = $"/tmp/privatekey_for_openssl_processing/{dataString}.rsa";
     string dataFilename = $"/tmp/privatekey_for_openssl_processing/{dataString})data.txt";
     string signatureFilename = $"/tmp/privatekey_for_openssl_processing/{dataString}_signature.txt";
     string signatureFilenameOut = $"/tmp/privatekey_for_openssl_processing/{dataString}_signature_out.txt";

string[] lines =
{
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----",
    privateKey,
    "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
};

File.WriteAllText(dataFilename, data);
File.WriteAllLines(publickey, lines);

Process openssl_sign = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "openssl",
        Arguments = $"dgst -sha256 -sign {publickey} -binary -out {signatureFilename} {dataFilename}", // use "-" to write output to stdout
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true, // enable redirecting STDIN
        RedirectStandardOutput = true, // enable redirecting STDOUT
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    },
};
// start the process
openssl_sign.Start();
// write data to STDIN of openssl process
openssl_sign.StandardInput.Write(data);
openssl_sign.StandardInput.Close();

return File.ReadAllText(signatureFilename).Replace("\n", "");
}
```

Here's my Javascript verification code:

```
function importEllipticPublicKey(pem) {
  // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
  if (!pem.startsWith("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----")) {
    pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"+pem;
  }
  if (!pem.endsWith("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----")) {
    pem = pem+"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
  }
  const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
  const pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
  const DANGEROUS_pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
  // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
  const binaryDerString = atob(DANGEROUS_pemContents);
  // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
  const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

  return crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "spki",
    binaryDer,
    {
      name: "ECDSA",
      namedCurve: "P-521"
    },
    true,
    ["verify"]
  );
}

async function VerifyPublickey(data, signature, publickey) {
  console.log("KEY DATA", await importEllipticPublicKey(`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  ${publickey}
  -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`));
  try {
    let enc = new TextEncoder();
    let encoded = enc.encode(data);
    publickey = publickey.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    publickey = publickey.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    
    let result = await crypto.subtle.verify(
      {
        name: "ECDSA",
        hash: "SHA-256",
      },
      await importEllipticPublicKey(`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
${publickey}
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`),
      signature,
      encoded
    );

    console.log("RESULT", result);

    if (result == true) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
    return false;
  }
}

const signature = Buffer.from(data.signature);
  if (!signature || signature.length == 0) {
    console.log("data.signature is missing.");
    return false;
  }

if (await VerifyPublickey(JSON.stringify(signedObject), signature, repairedSignedObject.publickey) != true) {
    console.log("SignedObject data does not match capability public key.");
    return false;
  }
```